# How do you debug MVC 4 API routes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a WP7 game that uses RESTsharp to communicate with my MVC4 RESTful server, but I often have issues making requests that work and therefore I want to debug where it fails.

This is an example where the Constructor on my `GameController` is hit, but the `Post` method is not hit, and I don't understand why.

Client code:

```
public void JoinRandomGame()
{
  client = new RestClient
  {
      CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
      BaseUrl = "http://localhost:21688/api/",
  };

  client.Authenticator = GetAuth();

  RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
  {
      RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
      Resource = "game/"

  };

  client.PostAsync(request, (response, ds) =>
  {});
}
```

Server code:

```
    public void Post(int id)
    {
        if (ControllerContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
        {
            //No auth
        }
        if (!loginManager.VerifyLogin(ControllerContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter))
        {
            //Failed login
        }

        string username;
        string password;
        LoginManager.DecodeBase64(ControllerContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter, out username, out password);
        gameManager.JoinRandomGame(username);
    }
```

My routes are like this

```
       routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "gameAPI",
            routeTemplate: "api/game/{gameId}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "game",
                gameId = RouteParameter.Optional
            }             
        );
```

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: I cant see the debugger information when I access my RESTful service through a WP7 emulator?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

RouteDebugger is good for figuring out which routes will/will not be hit.

http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger

Comment: Already proposed in comments above, but I cant see how that should tell me where it goes wrong? http://www.gratisimage.dk/graphic/images/2012/July/13/C044_50005206.jpg this is what I get with that and loookign at api/game/{gameId} controller = game, gameId = the stuff I did should work?

Comment: According to your screenshot, gameId is not optional. Try including gameId and see if it hits your route...

Comment: Note also that your Post action cannot accept an optional gameId. Consider either making it mandatory or making the parameter nullable (int? gameId) or setting a default value (int gameId = 0).

Comment: Rename your post parameter to gameId.

Comment: That dont do anything (I only renamed it because I tried removing the parameter (I dont use it, was only added to try to get it to hit the method))

Answer (score 119):

Another way is to add an event handler in `Global.asax.cs` to pick up the incoming request and then look at the route values in the VS debugger. Override the `Init` method as follows:

```
public override void Init()
{
    base.Init();
    this.AcquireRequestState += showRouteValues;
}

protected void showRouteValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context == null)
        return;
    var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(context)); 
}
```

Then set a breakpoint in `showRouteValues` and look at the contents of `routeData`.

Keep in mind that in a Web API project, the Http routes are in `WebApiConfig.cs`, not `RouteConfig.cs`.

Comment: Quick and dirty, just what I needed!

Comment: This doesn't scale to a solution with dozens/hundreds of controllers.

Comment: Where is this in aspnet6?

Answer (score 1):

You can try ASP.NET Web API Route Debugger. It is written for Web Api. https://trocolate.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/introducing-asp-net-web-api-route-debugger/
http://nuget.org/packages/WebApiRouteDebugger/

Comment: Note this package is for c#. Does not seem to support vb.net.

Comment: Tried this. Did not work for my ASP.NET MVC 5 project with Web API added on.  Then I completely messed up my project when I uninstalled it due to its many dependencies. Consider it install-only.

Comment: It messed-up even my Web API 2 project - why does a debugging tool need to add Razor, Twitter Bootstrap and other add-ons to a strictly JSON webservice? Phil Haack's tool is better, and very minimal.

Comment: I accidentally installed the package for the wrong project (just a dll library project), which couldn't have had routes debugged anyways. So I had twice as much leftover junk to clean up after I found it didn't work with MVC 5.

Answer (score 1):

There are more possibilities for testing the routes. You can try either manual testing or automated as part of unit tests.
Manual testing:

- [RouteDebugger](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger)
- [MVC API tracing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Automated testing:

- [MvcRouteTester](https://github.com/AnthonySteele/MvcRouteTester).

Answer (score 0):

Is GameController deriving from ApiController ?
Are you using WebApi ?

If not then i think the "/api/" is reserved for new WebApi feature. Try changing your routing and controller name to "gameapi"

If however you are using WebApi.

Then remove api from yor BaseUrl

```
  client = new RestClient
  {
      CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
      BaseUrl = "http://localhost:21688/",
  };
```

Comment: Yes I have it working, but its just when I have some that dont work I cant figure out a good way to do it but my controller is like this http://pastebin.com/qki60LyU

Comment: Then you can use RouteDebugger from "flem s" link it's the same thing from my link :) Just run it on your page that is used by WP7, do it in the browser. Also you can think about installing Elmah - http://nuget.org/packages/elmah

Comment: That just gives me an XML file (Therefor now information from routedebugger) and also when I run it I hit my Get and not my Post (Which works fine)

Comment: is your Post action decorated by [HttpPost] attribute ?

Comment: No http://pastebin.com/qki60LyU havent been necessary before, and my Get requests work and I just tried using it but no dice