# Is there a way I can debug a route in ASP. MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In the past I have used some code by I think Scott Hanselman of Microsoft. However now I am using MVC5 and I don't think that code is valid any more.

Is there a way I can trace routes taken in MVC5 so that I can know why I see messages like:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Answer (score 21):

I know it is late for the OP but for anyone else trying to debug 404 errors I've found a way to intercept the route result and see why it is failing to find the resource.

In `Global.asax.cs` override Init like this:

```
    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
        this.AcquireRequestState += showRouteValues;
    }

    protected void showRouteValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context == null)
            return;
        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
    }
```

The `routeData` variable will hold the route info as it is being interpreted. I've tested this on MVC5.

I originally bumped into this method in another answer by Paul Evans, this is the link (thanks to @porcus for finding it): [stackoverflow.com/a/25466524](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25466524)

Comment: Here's the link to the other SO answer you may have gotten that code snippet from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25466524  
And I commend you for trying to provide attribution.

Comment: @porcus that is the original answer indeed, I'll update my answer to link to it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). One of the modules that it comes with is a Routes module which will allow you to see details about the routes that were checked, values that were passed in and which ones matched (if any).

Comment: This is good if my route is matched by some controller, but how can debug routes which result in a 404 error?

Comment: @AdrianGrigore check out the answer I added, it might help you with 404 errors.

Comment: Glimpse does not really help if the routing goes wrong and you try to figure out why.