# Debug Attribute Routing in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) package contains a handler called LogRoutesHandler that "emits the routes in the RouteTable to a browser".

Is there something similar in the new MVC5 attribute routing functionality?

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30760133/169714

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also miss the routes.axd feature of AttributeRouting in ASP MVC 5. I am using currently using Glimpse to debug routes. It's not quite the same, far from friendly compared to routes.axd, but it helps.