# How to log the selected ASP.NET Core MVC route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-routing

Is there a simple way to log (using nlog, e.g. `log.Debug(…)`) the selected route in an ASP.NET Core MVC application? I use `HttpGet`/`HttpPost` attributes to define my routes, and I am looking for a simple way to log the route that MVC chooses to handle for each incoming request.

> **Note:** Similar questions have been answered, but they relate to debugging and analyzing routes:
>
> - [How do you debug MVC 4 API routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473038/how-do-you-debug-mvc-4-api-routes)
> - [ASP.NET Routing Debugger](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/)

For my purposes, though, I just want to know which route MVC chose to handle for the request and have it logged.  (And, ideally, I don't want to add a log to each controller method; there must be some way to do this once generically for all incoming requests.)

Comment: In .NET Core, you can follow this tutorial to achieve what you want: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/aspnet-core-logging

Comment: thanks, yes, this works,  so to clarify for others, once NLog or other logger  is setup,  I found the information in the Microsoft logger named Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher

Answer (score 2):

a simple generic way of logging all request is using a registered middleware component.

```
    public class PerformanceMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public PerformanceMiddleware(RequestDelegate requestDelegate)
        {
            _next = requestDelegate;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            var nextTask = _next.Invoke(httpContext);
            nextTask.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var time = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                var requestString = $"[{httpRequest.Method}]{httpRequest.Path}?{httpRequest.QueryString}";
                if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    .. log.Info ..($"{time}ms {requestString}");
                }
                else
                {
                    .. log.Warn ..($"{time}ms [{t.Status}] - {requestString}", t.Exception?.InnerException);
                }
            });
            return nextTask;
        }
    }
```

*this also logs the execution time*

In your startup you register it as the first, before `UseMvc` and any other middleware components.

```
            app.UseMiddleware<PerformanceMiddleware>();
```

Comment: The httpRequest object referenced here is actually from httpContext.Request.
You can populate it by saying:
            var httpRequest = httpContext.Request;

Answer (score -4):

On IIS, you can use the `web.config` file. In this file, by default, there is an option `stdoutLogEnabled=false`. Switch it to `true`. A log will be generated with the info you want.

Edit : Updated my answer to specify it's only correct for IIS according to the comments below

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes I used that option in my last Web Api written in .NET Core 2.2

Comment: Not sure this helps, comment from Rahul in the question works.

Comment: @An0d NET Core you should have a web.config file? Is this correct? I don't see a web.config file in my .NET Core project.

Comment: In my last 3 ASP.NET Core projects. A web.config file was included which look like this
https://gist.github.com/An0d/a8be6b88e9ba4983c2ff25edad525a9d

you can see the options `stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"`

With those options, no change in code needed to log some informations about routes etc...

Comment: ASP.NET Core Configuration with web.config is documented here [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configuration-with-webconfig)

Comment: That is on IIS during deployment specifically for the `ASP.NET Core Module`.

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't use web.config. It's produced as part of the publish just in case you happen to deploy to IIS, and `stdoutLogFile` would only be applicable in that one specific scenario. This is not the solution.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. But when deployed on Azure App Service the web.config is taken into account. You can specify the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT through web.config for example. So I did not think that web.config was just for IIS. As I only deployed my applications on IIS or on Azure App Service I thought it was a correct solution. Sorry

Comment: Edited my answer to specify it's only correct for IIS